# Adding a header to source files with Bash

Tags: bash

I have a script that adds a string C++ source files:

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.h' -or -name '*.cpp');
    do sed -i '1s/^/<added text> /' $f;
done;
```

How to make it add a multiline variable value?

Tried this, but with not success:

```
h=$'//Copyright 2021 My Corporation\n//Authors: me and others\n'
```

variable `h` becomes single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ed`, not `sed`, to edit files.

You also don't need to use `find` to locate the files if you're using `bash`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

h=$'//Copyright 2021 My Corporation\n//Authors: me and others\n'

# Turn on recursive globbing and extended globbing and have patterns that
# fail to match expand to an empty string
shopt -s globstar extglob nullglob
for f in **/*.@(h|cpp); do
  # Add the contents of the variable h at the beginning of the file
  # Note: no lines in $h should be just a period as that signals end of
  # text input mode.
  ed -s "$f" <<EOF
1i
$h
.
w
EOF
done
```

---

If you *must* use `sed` for some reason, you also want to use its `i\` command, not `s` (People tend to forget that `sed` even *has* other commands), which inserts the following lines of text until one without a backslash at the end marks the last line of input. Some `bash` parameter expansion to massage your variable into the appropriate form is needed, of course:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

h=$'//Copyright 2021 My Corporation\n//Authors: me and others\n'

# Add a newline at the very beginning, and a backlash at the end
# of each line
h=$'\n'"${h//$'\n'/$'\\\n'}"

# Or just format the original string appropriately at the start
# h=$'\n//Copyright 2021 My Corporation\\\n//Authors: me and others\\\n'

shopt -s globstar extglob nullglob
for f in **/*.@(h|cpp); do
    sed -i -e "1i\\$h" "$f"
done

# If using GNU sed, you can avoid the loop:
# sed -si -e "1i\\$h" **/*.@(h|cpp)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can be a bit temperamental when dealing with embedded (single-character) `\n`'s; we can get around this a couple ways ...

Sample input file:

```
$ cat xx
1
2
3
```

A couple `sed` ideas depending on how the `${h}` variable is defined:

**1)** `${h}` defined with literal/single-char `\n`:

```
$ h=$'//Copyright 2021 My Corporation\n//Authors: me and others\n'
$ sed "1 s|^|${h//$'\n'/\\n}|" xx
```

Where:

- `1 s|^|` - line 1, replace start of line with ...
- `${h//$'\n'/\\n}` - change all single-char `\n` into 3-char `\\n` (escaped `\` + `n`)
- **NOTE:** because `/` characters show up in the data we need a different delimiter for the `sed` command, hence the `|`

**2)** `${h}` defined with 2-char `\` + `n`:

```
$ h='//Copyright 2021 My Corporation\n//Authors: me and others\n'
$ sed "1 s|^|${h//\/\\}|" xx*
```

Where:

- `1 s|^|` - line 1, replace start of line with ...
- `${h//\/\\}` - escape all `\` (**NOTE:** this could cause issues with `\` that are not to be interpreted as control characters)
- **NOTE:** because `/` characters show up in the data we need a different delimiter for the `sed` command, hence the `|`

Both of these generate:

```
//Copyright 2021 My Corporation
//Authors: me and others
1
2
3
```

Once OP is satisfied with the result the `-i` flag can be added to perform the inplace update.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed is overkill and limit you with sed syntax.

Use `cat` instead:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Some helpful settings to avoid editing the core code
corporation='Example INC'
authors=(
  'me'
  'someone'
  'someone-else'
)

# Capture the year (require bash 4.2+)
# If older bash, use year="$(date '+%Y')"
printf -v year '%(%Y)T'

# Be sure tmp_file variable does not exist (may have been exported)
unset tmp_file

# Prepare EXIT trap to clean-up temporary file
trap 'rm -f -- "$tmp_file"' EXIT

# Safely create a temporary file to hold changes
tmp_file="$(mktemp)"

# Find .h or .cpp files and make it a null delimited records stream
find . \( -name '*.h' -or -name '*.cpp' \) -print0 |
  # Iterate the null delimited file names
  while read -r -d '' cpp_file; do
    # Skip files already containing the copyright header
    tail -n2 "$cpp_file" | grep -qF ' * Copyright' && continue

    # If successfully merging here-document header with file
    # into the temporary file
    if cat - "$cpp_file" >"$tmp_file" <<EOF
/*
 * Copyright ${year} ${corporation}
 * Authors: ${authors[*]}
 *
 */
EOF
      # then copy the temporary file over
      then cp "$tmp_file" "$cpp_file"
    fi
  done
```